# How do I capture images from rtsp stream and save them without being corrupted?

Tags: python, opencv, rtsp, ip-camera, hikvision

I'm trying to use python to capture a photo from my ip cameras every 1 minute and save it as a file for later use.
I'm still not good at python and I don't get why some of the times I get the right image and sometimes I get a corrupted gray image.
I'm using hikvision api to get the rtsp stream and while the stream is working sometimes the images are still fully gray.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
import cv2
import time

count = 0
while True:
    for x in range(1, 9):
        count = count +1
        RTSP_URL = f'rtsp://user:password@ip:port/ISAPI/Streaming/Channels/{x}01'
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(RTSP_URL, cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
        result, image = cap.read()
        if result:
            cv2.imwrite(f"pictures/{x}{count}.png", image)
        time.sleep(60)
```

I would be happy to hear suggestions to find the best way to do this task.

Comment: Are you getting corrupted images if you remove `time.sleep(60)`? For testing, you may add `cv2.imshow('image', image)` and `cv2.waitKey(1)` for showing the video.

Comment: @Rotem
thanks for commenting, after changing that it still shows the gray images and sometimes working images.
what's interesting is that when I try to make it a substream(a lower quality option offered by the API) it works without corrupted images.

Comment: No I see... you are reading from 8 different streams. Try adding `cap.release()` after `result, image = cap.read()`. That way you are going to close and reopen the connection every minute. I don't think we can use new `cap = cv2.VideoCapture` without executing `cap.release()`. In case you want to hold 8 RTSP connections open, use a list of 8 `cap` objects. Open the 8 `cap` objects before the `while True`, and use `cap[x-1].read()`. Make sure that the CPU load is not too high.

Comment: @Rotem thanks again for helping me!
After trying both ideas It looks like the situation doesn't change. Perhaps it's the problem with the API?
Here is a link for the corrupted image I get https://imgur.com/pmZloii

Comment: try this https://github.com/Cacsjep/pyrtsputils/blob/main/snapshot_generator.py

Comment: @Christoph great job with the GitHub page!
It looks like the same problem still exist.
Most likely it's not due to the code though.

Comment: Please send a screenshot from your hik camera (Stream settings) also how do you get the stream over LAN or WAN ? I think that is a network releated issue that when u decrease the stream quality your results are better as you wrote on a previous comment

Comment: @Christoph I'm running it on my local network.
Is there a way to check if the issue is network related?

Comment: first try to ping and check the repsonese times, should be some ms, on LAN it should be 1 ms, if is ok than run your rtsp stream with ffplay and look if there rtp packes missing (ffplay writes this to the console if this happen)